# Days delta by ID

Tags: pandas

I want to create a variable that indicates the delta in days, for each ID.
Also, to create a variable that indicates the cumulative delta in days, the cumulative variable will reset when the Y variable is equal 1, but from the next row, each ID individually.

Data illustration:

```
ID  Date        X
A   07/16/2019  ..
A   07/19/2019  ..
A   07/20/2019  ..
A   07/22/2019  ..
A   07/23/2019  ..
B   07/27/2019  ..
B   07/28/2019  ..
B   07/30/2019  ..
```

Expected result:

```
ID  Date        X   Y   Days    Cum_days
A   07/16/2019  ..  0   0       0
A   07/19/2019  ..  0   3       3
A   07/20/2019  ..  1   1       4
A   07/22/2019  ..  0   2       2
A   07/23/2019  ..  0   1       3
B   07/27/2019  ..  0   0       0
B   07/28/2019  ..  1   1       1
B   07/30/2019  ..  0   2       2
```

Comment: is your expect output correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use even when group ends or starts with 1 in column Y:

```
#convert column to datetimes
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
#shift 1 values per groups, with cumulative copy
g = df.groupby('ID')['Y'].apply(lambda x: x.shift().fillna(0).cumsum())
```

Or better is replace first `NaN`s by previous values by `bfill`:

```
g = df.groupby('ID')['Y'].apply(lambda x: x.shift().bfill().cumsum())
```

---

```
#get difference per groups
df['Days'] = df.groupby('ID')['Date'].diff().dt.days.fillna(0).astype(int)  
#cumulative sum per groups
df['Cum_days'] = df.groupby(['ID', g])['Days'].cumsum()
print (df)
  ID       Date   X  Y  Days  Cum_days
0  A 2019-07-16  ..  0     0         0
1  A 2019-07-19  ..  0     3         3
2  A 2019-07-20  ..  1     1         4
3  A 2019-07-22  ..  0     2         2
4  A 2019-07-23  ..  0     1         3
5  B 2019-07-27  ..  0     0         0
6  B 2019-07-28  ..  1     1         1
7  B 2019-07-30  ..  0     2         2
```

Comment: Sorry, maybe I didn't explain my self well. The cumulative variable should be reset when Y variable got 1, from the next row, but not only in the next row. I will edit the data, and add another row for 'A' ID.

Comment: @qwerty - then it is simplier, do you need shift `1` per groups?

Comment: @qwerty - Still my solution is wrong? Or working well both solutions in your data?

Comment: Still doesn't work. Look at the expected result in row 4

Comment: @qwerty -- ops, you are right, so answer was edited.

Comment: it would not make sense to end or start a ID group with a 1 in column Y. My answer also work

Answer (score 2):

Yo can use if never group ends or starts with 1 in column Y:

```
df['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df['Days']=df.groupby('ID')['Date'].diff().dt.days.fillna(0)
df['cum_days']=df.groupby([df['Y'].shift().fillna(0).cumsum(),'ID'])['Days'].cumsum()
print(df)

  ID       Date   X  Y  Days    cum_days
0  A 2019-07-16  ..  0   0.0         0.0
1  A 2019-07-19  ..  0   3.0         3.0
2  A 2019-07-20  ..  1   1.0         4.0
3  A 2019-07-22  ..  0   2.0         2.0
4  A 2019-07-23  ..  0   1.0         3.0
5  B 2019-07-27  ..  0   0.0         0.0
6  B 2019-07-28  ..  1   1.0         1.0
7  B 2019-07-30  ..  0   2.0         2.0
```

Comment: I understand what you mean, but how to get the output he expects?

Comment: I do not agree that this is necessary. It could only affect if a group ends or starts with 1 in column Y ... this would not make sense. i don't copy @jezrael. Don't work my solution @qwerty?

Comment: I understand that: `It could only affect if a group ends or starts with 1 in column Y` would be an unlikely case.

Comment: So if add to answer, I really like remove downvote.

Comment: I agree with you

Comment: Why not plus1? Thank you very much, why I add comment for downvote I try explain in my profile ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2901002/jezrael?tab=profile))